# Explode array values without looping PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way I can explode the array values of a big array without iterating through each item?

For e.g. I have

```
$Array = [
    'Foo and Bar',
    'Bar and Baz',
    'Baz and Foo'
];
```

I want

```
$Array1 = [
    'Foo',
    'Bar',
    'Baz'
];
$Array2 = [
    'Bar',
    'Baz',
    'Foo'
];
```

I can achieve this by simply doing a `foreach` loop. Like this

```
foreach ($Array as $Value) {
    $DataEx = explode(' and ', $Value);
    $Array1[] = $DataEx[0];
    $Array2[] = $DataEx[1];
}
```

I have came across answers where some iteration is being suggested. 
But I seek to know if it can be achieved by any array function of PHP or by any combination of such array functions.

Comment: Any array function __iterates__ over an array. So it's useless to complicate code just because you want to __hide__ iteration.

Comment: After all those extra 5 lines of code are really clogging up your code.

Comment: Agree with @u_mulder and BTW what 2 output you want from your initial array seems not to be possible without iteration code.

Comment: any reason for not using a `foreach()`?

Comment: Maybe answers given below but i will recommend you to go with your own solution as it is simple easy and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach without a "foreach" loop in your code.

```
$array = [
  'Foo and Bar',
  'Bar and Baz',
  'Baz and Foo'
];

$explodedArray = array_map( function( $v ){ return explode( ' and ', $v ); }, $array );

$Array1 = array_column( $explodedArray, 0 );
$Array2 = array_column( $explodedArray, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk`

```
$Array = [
    'Foo and Bar',
    'Bar and Baz',
    'Baz and Foo'
];

$return = [];
array_walk($Array, function($v) use(&$return){
    list($return['Array1'][], $return['Array2'][]) = preg_split('/\s+and+\s/i', $v);
});
extract($return);
```

demo : https://paiza.io/projects/gGYT_UfojR9odDc7KoHOHg

*Output*

```
// Array1
$Array1 = [
    'Foo',
    'Bar',
    'Baz'
];

// Array2
$Array2 = [
    'Bar',
    'Baz',
    'Foo'
];
```